# Micromod nrf52840 sniffer

Tags: arduino-nano-ble, nrf52, mbed

Can I use the Micromod nrf52840 processor module, Micromod ATP carrier, with Nano 33 type bootloader and modify the ArduinoBLE library or modify the MBED OS abstraction layer and make a promiscuous BLE sniffer that will output something, preferably a Wireshark compatible capture file to the main serial COM port and save the output from arduino IDE?

Comment: maybe you can, maybe you cannot, we do not know what skill you have